# Problem with cache and memory from university class

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management, memory-allocation, cache

In my university class, I received this homework assignment on computer architecture, but I don't know how to solve it. I already know that the correct answer is 0, but I don't understand why. Could someone help me?

Problem:
The byte-addressable memory has a 16-bit address. The directly addressed cache has 7-bit tags and 8-byte rows. You need to provide the cache row address if the memory address is #8614. The result should be given in hexadecimal, omitting the # sign.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your directly-mapped cache has 128 cache lines of 8 bytes. So, in a memory address, the 3 least significant bits (bits `[0:3]`) are used to compute the location *inside the cache line* while the rest of the bits are used to target a specific cache line inside the cache. I can only *assume* that the 7 next bits (bits `[3:10]`) are used for this purpose.
Therefore, memory address `#8614` corresponds to byte 4 in cache line `#42`, because `#8614 % 8 = 4` and `(#8614 // 8) % 128 = #42`.

Comment: Let me add that we all know that 42 is always the answer.

Comment: What are cache tags for? Please add to your answer: How did you compute the number of cache line address bits, the number of cache lines?